# How monitor when system calls are triggered while in root shell?

Tags: linux-kernel, firmware

I am trying to debug my embedded device by monitoring when system calls are being triggered. As of now I have a root shell connected to the device. When I do the `$ top` command I can see my executable `/system/bin/main` is running but within in this file I have multiple ioctl calls. What I want to do is "be notified" or monitor when these system calls are actually being triggered in real time. For example I know I can trigger an ioctl call by sending a request to the camera but I do not know how to view that in the root shell. I am only using ioctl in this file.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs either on StackOverflow or Unix & Linux SE.

Comment: Is there a log occurring？

Comment: /system/bin/main suggests that this is android. For linux the standard tool for years was `strace` but these days `bpftrace` might be a better choice.

Comment: It is not android... the name of my executable is just main. This is linux 32 bit little endian Mips @icarus

Comment: OK. use strace. If the executable is already running the you can use `strace -p PID -f -e ioctl` (filling in the correct value for the process id of course). otherwise use `strace -f -e ioctl main`.

Comment: Thank you! @icarus

Answer (score 1):

There is an utility called `strace`, which does exactly that: attaches to a program and displays its system calls. You could use it like `strace <program>`, but then it would be mixing with the normal program output and interfering with it. A better way (that requires root access though) would be to first run the program, then `pgrep <program>` to get its PID or find it manually via `top`, and then in a separate shell run as root `strace -p <pid>`. You could then grep there for `ioctl()` and pipe that to `notify-send` or a bell echo via `xargs` to get notified every time.  Also, it is possible to trace just `ioctl()` by passing `-e trace=ioctl` to `strace` (credit to @aviro 's comment), and by adding the `-f` argument it would also trace any child processes created. A full command would probably look like this:

```
strace -f -e trace=ioctl -p <pid> &>&1 | tee ioctl.log | tee >(xargs -L1 echo -e \b)
```

Omit the last command to simply output the ioctls to the stdout. Swap `echo -e \b` for a `notify-send` or any other notification creator of your preference that would get called every time a new ioctl happens.

Comment: There are **a lot** of problems with your answer: 1) strace writes the output by default to `STDERR`  so the `tee` won't catch it. 2) It will not follow forks and children. 3) It will write a lot of data to the disk (the `grep` is after the `tee`) and will slow down the application significantly. 4) It's possible to tell strace to catch only specefic syscalls using `-e trace=ioctl`.

Comment: Can I use this while the the main file is already in execution? Currently my file runs right after boot so I am not manually starting it with a command. Starting another instance would also not work. @aviro

Comment: @aviro, many thanks, answer edited

Comment: @AskedSuperior yes, it would attach to any running process.

Comment: Your redirection is wrong. `&>1` will redirect both `STDIN` and `STDOUT` to a file called "1". It should be `2>&1`. In addition, I would add `-qq` flag to `strace` to suppress messages about process exit status and avoid clutter. Last thing, `echo -e \b` will not produce beep. Unquoted `\b` will be interpreted as the literal `b`. Quoted `"\b"` is interpreted as a backspace. The right sequence for the bell with `echo` is `\a` (alert), so you need `echo -e "\a"`.